# PIC16F870 frequency counter

Tags: counter, frequency, pic

For school, my projectgroup and I have to build a capacitive revolution counter. A motor turns a mechanical capacitor, the resulting sinewave is converted to a square wave: 5v=1, 0v=0.

We have to read-out this signal with a PIC16F870 microcontroller. Our experience with assembly (required) is very limited, and we're not the only projectgroup struggeling with this. The revolutions per minute need to be displayed on a LCD and must be able to display between 0 and 255 revolutions (so at least it's limited to a single 8 bit registry).

The mentioned PIC is a RISC controller, runs at 4Mhz and is 8 bit.

Can someone help us with this, give us some advice, maybe link us to an example? at this point we're more than happy with a dirty, simple code that at least works.

Thanks,
Joost

Comment: use one of the internal timers to count the time between the pulses. Feed the square wave into one of the interrupts. 1/time is frequency.

Comment: Agree with kenny on strategy. Also you can't expect to cut and paste assembler. It is very close to the hardware and someone on your group will have to become proficient if you hope to get anything working. Fortunately it is not hard if you take the time to learn. Lots of good tutorials around the web and this is an online PIC sim you can play about with [here](http://www.microcontrollerjs.com)

Comment: Thanks guys. How do I "feed" the square wave into an interupt, and what's the point of that?